# Storing Credentials for Offline Access in Datastore

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am using the `oauth2decorator_from_clientsecrets()` to query various Google API's. I have to store the credentials so I can access the user's data offline (in a cron job). I have the following Credentials class Set up:

```
class CredentialsModel(db.Model):
    credentials = CredentialsProperty()
```

I try to store the credentials in the Datastore as follows:

```
if decorator.has_credentials():
    storage = StorageByKeyName(CredentialsModel, user.user_id(),'credentials')                
    credentials = decorator.get_credentials()
    storage.put(credentials)
```

I receive the following error:

```
 AttributeError: 'OAuth2DecoratorFromClientSecrets' object has no attribute 'get_credentials'
```

When I looked at the [documentation](https://google-api-python-client.googlecode.com/hg/docs/epy/oauth2client.appengine.OAuth2Decorator-class.html#get_credentials) it looks like the decorator should have get_credentials().

I am going about this correct way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example of usage:

Additional imports needed for the below code:

```
from google.appengine.api import users
from google.appengine.api import memcache
import pickle
```

Trigger flow example:

```
flow = OAuth2WebServerFlow(
            client_id=client_id,
            client_secret=client_secret,
            scope=scope,

            access_type = 'offline',
            approval_prompt='force',
            redirect_uri=self.request.relative_url('/admin/auth_return'))
# Get the url now
authorize_url = flow.step1_get_authorize_url()
# Save flow object in memcache for later retrieval on OAuth callback,
# and redirect this session to Google's OAuth 2.0 authorization site.
logging.info('saving flow for user ' + user.user_id())
memcache.set(user.user_id(), pickle.dumps(flow))
# redirect directly
self.redirect(authorize_url, abort=True)
```

Save

```
...

user = users.get_current_user()
logging.info('retrieving flow for user ' + user.user_id())
flow = pickle.loads(memcache.get(user.user_id()))

credentials = flow.step2_exchange(self.request.params)
StorageByKeyName(CredentialsModel, user.user_id(), 'credentials').locked_put(credentials)
```

Get

```
# here is how you can get them
credentials = StorageByKeyName(CredentialsModel, user.user_id(),'credentials').locked_get()
...
```

Comment: Where do you get the input for the `locked_put()` from the decorator?

Comment: @Alex sorry I misplaced the code. Ah this editor. I put it in memcache and then pickle it. See updated answer

Comment: I was originally trying to avoid using this flow but it works great! Thanks. Only problem is that not all of my scopes are being recognized. I passed them in as a list of strings - that should work right?

Comment: @Alex to get more insight on you issue open a new question describing where you are, and validate this one if it helped you. This we can focus on one problem at a time.

Comment: why do you need to pickle flow in the first place? Flow doesn't contain any data that is related to the user as far as I can see.

Comment: @Jonathan It has a `flow` object that needs to be stored in cache in order to survive a request lifecyclce

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand what would happen if you just recreated the flow object. I would appreciate if you could explain that to me. Are you saying it wouldn't be possible to execute `step2_exchange` without the original flow object?

Comment: @Jonathan Althoght it has been sometime since I coded on app engine yes I do think so. The point is that you get generate a unique flow1 for user. When he returns to the endpoint you process that. If you need an example check my personal website auth flow: https://github.com/jimmykane/dimitrioskanellopoulos.com/blob/master/controllers/auth/google_apis.py

Comment: ah, now it makes sense!

Comment: @Jonathan Glad to help. Took me also sometime to coop with the Auth flow

Comment: @JimmyKane Does this still work on App Engine? user = users.get_current_user() fails for us on App Engine when the redirect back occurs. We get a "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'user_id'"

Comment: @Praxiteles not sure anymore. Haven't used app engine lately. If you find out what the case is please update.